# Jack microphone-only detected as headset

Tags: microphone, audio-jack

I am trying to connect my jack microphone in my laptop, but it's detected as a headeset and I cannot record anything there.

**Microphone model**: Condenser Microphone SF-666 
**Connector type**: Jack 
**Laptop**: Lenovo v330 
**OS**: Kubuntu 19.04

Answer (score 0):

go to the file /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and if

A) This file only have 43 lines of code, add those two:

```
options snd-hda-intel position fix=1
options snd-hda-intel model=,dell-headset-multi
```

B) This file have 44 lines of code just add:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=,dell-headset-multi
```

And reboot. If still doesn't work try without the coma.